# Chainlink says my EVM node is unreachable to localhost ganache

Tags: ganache, chainlink

I have followed the instructions from chainlink doc [here](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/running-a-chainlink-node). In the instruction, instead of sepolia, I renamed to ganache because it will be linking with my ganache EVM.

As everything is setup, my chainlink operator UI is running, and able to login, but in Nodes, my EVM state saying unreachable.

My ganache RPC server is 0.0.0.0:8545 and chain ID is set 1337, but nothing happened.
Please help, what am I missing here despite followed the instructions from docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For smooth communication between Chainlink and Ganache running in Docker, ensure Ganache is configured to listen on the Docker IP address. Also, double-check the database and localhost settings in the Chainlink configuration for proper connections.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It definitely work now! in docker there is `host.docker.internal` rather 0.0.0.0